# Is a minimal surface still minimal when immersed in $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, minimal-surfaces

If we consider an isometric immersion $\bar{f}:M^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$ which is minimal, is it true that 
$$
f:M^2\to\mathbb{R}^4
$$
(defined by $\bar{f}$ on the first three coordinates and $0$ on the last one) is still minimal?
I tried to prove this but I couldn't find how the mean curvature vector field changes by extending the immersion in a constant manner on one coordinate.

Is there any literature dealing with this question?

Comment: Yes, a straight in $R^2$ which is a geodesic is still geodesic in $R^3$. The other coordinate is just zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes because the inclusion $i:\mathbb{R}^3\hookrightarrow{}\mathbb{R}^4$ is Totally Geodesic (this is obvious by the form of the covariant derivative in $\mathbb{R}^n$).

What holds true is the following:

Proposition: Given $f:M^r\to N^k$ minimal immersion and $g:N^k\to P^l$ totally geodesic, then $g\circ f:M^r\to P^l$ is minimal.

Proof: Split the second fundamental form of $M^r\subset P^l$, in the tangent and normal part of $N(\subset P)$. The normal part vanishes by definition of Totally geodesic submanifold, hence, taking the trace, we obtain the mean curvature of $M^r\subset P^l$ equalling the mean curvature of $M^r\subset N^k$ (Note that the covariant derivative of $N$ is just the tangential part of the covariant derivative of $P$). By minimality, the latest is zero and we conclude. $\blacksquare$

As a reference, I suggest Chapter 6 of Riemannian Geometry by do Carmo (note that exercise 3 has the same flavour).